# CHROME JS error: "GET http://localhost/loading.gif undefined (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I get this error on the Chrome (10.0.648.204) console (see image):

[image: Chrome console undefined error]

So what I'm doing here is when the user submits the form, an image (preloaded) is inserted in a div (jQuery) and positioned on the button.

The image was preloaded in the HTML but is hidden (display:none).

When the visitor submits the form then the image is inserted AGAIN after the form submit started (so the animated gif dont stop).

Works perfectly in FF and IE, but not in Chrome 10

Any ideas what its happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've seen this "undefined" error in Chrome, it's usually because I'm making a request, then canceling it. Usually it's an AJAX request, but I suppose it could be an image too. Is it possible that you're moving the image while it's in the process of loading?

Comment: I changed the way my script works. Now instead of setting the image "display:none" in the CSS file, I do it with jQuery on document ready. And I only reload the image if the browser used is IE, I dont need to reload it if its Chrome or FF...